# Cannot convert double to double * (gauss elimination) project on machine programming

Tags: c, arrays, function

Hey guys this is my first post here

this is something small part of a thing im working on

to remove the gauss errors in machines

the code is giving an error
like `In function double* uptri(double (*)[17],int):cannot convert 'double (*)[17]' to 'double*' in assignment`

any kind of help is much appreciated

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

main()
{
    double prob[16][17], GE[16][17],soln[16];
    double *q,*r;
    q=&GE[0][0];
    r=&soln[0];

    double* uptri(double[16][17], int);
    double* solve(double[16][17], int);
    int n,i,j;

    n=2;

    prob[0][0]=2;
    prob[0][1]=3;
    prob[0][2]=1;
    prob[1][0]=1;
    prob[1][1]=4;
    prob[1][2]=2;

    q=uptri(prob,n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
            printf("%lf\n",GE[i][j]);

    r=solve(GE,n);

    printf("Soln\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%lf\n",soln[i]);

}

double* uptri(double A[16][17],int n)
{
    int i,j,k;
    double *p,temp;
    p=&A[16][17];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(k=i+1;k<n;k++)
        {
            temp=A[k][i]/A[i][i];
            for(j=i;j<=n;j++)
                A[k][j]=A[k][j]-temp*A[i][j];
        }

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
                printf("%lf\n",A[i][j]);

        return p;   
}

double* solve(double A[16][17], int n)
{
    int i,j,k;
    double soln[16],*p,sum;
    p=&soln[0];
    soln[n-1]=A[n-1][n]/A[n-1][n-1];

    for(i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(j=n-1;j>i;j--)
            sum=sum+A[i][j]*soln[j];
            soln[i]=(A[i][n]-sum)/A[i][i];
    }

    return p;
}
```

Comment: `p=&A[16][17]` ? Which are boundaries of your array? Where does `p` point to?

Comment: this `p=&A[16][17]` is clearly wrong. What did you want to do with that?

Comment: I don't see the error you're seeing, but what is the point of `p` in `uptri()`? As others have noted, your assignment of `p` is wrong, but the function never modifies it and just returns it as is. What is that supposed to be doing?

I also see a problem in `solve()` – you're setting `p` to point to something declared locally and returning that pointer. After the function returns, the values of any local variables are undefined, so that pointer doesn't point to anything useful.

Comment: "The code is giving an error like" - Yeah, and I'm sure it actually gives you a line number too. What is that? I mean, in this case, it's pretty obvious, but it's polite to give people the whole message, rather than expecting them to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the compiler error that you do, but you have undefined behavior.

In `solve`, `soln` is part of its stack frame, so when it returns `p` will point to "thin air". That is, the stack frame can be overwritten immediately, and thus, the `soln` values

The easy way to fix this is to redefine `solve` as:

```
void solve(double *soln,double A[16][17], int n)
```

Then *remove* the stack frame definition from within `solve`:

```
double soln[16]
```

Also, `p` isn't needed.

Then, call it from main with:

```
solve(soln,GE,n);
```

Now, `solve` will return its data into `main`'s `soln`

Also, note that setting `p` in `uptri` points past the end of array (again, UB), but I didn't fix that because the function return isn't really used.

Here is a version that compiles and runs:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double* uptri(double[16][17], int);
void solve(double *,double[16][17], int);

int
main()
{
    double prob[16][17], GE[16][17],soln[16];
    //q=&GE[0][0];

    int n,i,j;

    n=2;

    prob[0][0]=2;
    prob[0][1]=3;
    prob[0][2]=1;
    prob[1][0]=1;
    prob[1][1]=4;
    prob[1][2]=2;

    /*-q=-*/ uptri(prob,n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
            printf("%lf\n",GE[i][j]);

    solve(soln,GE,n);

    printf("Soln\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%lf\n",soln[i]);

    return 0;
}

double* uptri(double A[16][17],int n)
{
    int i,j,k;
    double *p,temp;
    p=&A[16][17];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(k=i+1;k<n;k++)
        {
            temp=A[k][i]/A[i][i];
            for(j=i;j<=n;j++)
                A[k][j]=A[k][j]-temp*A[i][j];
        }

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
                printf("%lf\n",A[i][j]);

        return p;
}

void
solve(double *soln,double A[16][17], int n)
{
    int i,j;
    double sum;

    soln[n-1]=A[n-1][n]/A[n-1][n-1];

    for(i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(j=n-1;j>i;j--)
            sum=sum+A[i][j]*soln[j];
            soln[i]=(A[i][n]-sum)/A[i][i];
    }
}
```

Comment: tq so much sir...perfectly understood